# How to map libcurl options to curl command

Tags: curl, libcurl

I have some code which call libcurl to upload files to https site, these code works very well. Now I want to upload these files in curl command, so my questions is how to map libcurl options into curl command options? Thanks. I know there's an option --libcurl which can map curl command options into libcurl,  but it can't work for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such easy automated way to convert a libcurl-using program into the curl command line equivalents. But if you have the full HTTP request recorded, you can get help to convert the entire raw protocol trace into a curl command line using [h2c](https://curl.haxx.se/h2c/) - "http headers to curl".